# Enum returning object (NSError)

Tags: swift, enums

This relatively straight forward `enum`, compiles just fine, but ...

```
public protocol AuthKitErrorProtocol {
    var error: NSError { get }
}

enum AuthKitError: AuthKitErrorProtocol {
    case SignInFailedInvalidUsernamePassword
    case SignInFailedInvalidSecondFactor

    var error: NSError {
        let (codeK: Int,
        userInfoK: Dictionary<String, String>
        ) = {
            switch self {
            case .SignInFailedInvalidUsernamePassword:
                return (1000,
                    [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Operation failed.",
                        NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "Invalid usename or password",
                        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: "Please try again" ]
                )

            case .SignInFailedInvalidSecondFactor:
                return (1001,
                    [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Operation failed.",
                        NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "Invalid second factor code",
                        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: "Please try again" ]
                )

            default:
                return (-999,
                    [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Operation failed.",
                        NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "Unknown reason",
                        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: "Please call customer support" ]
                )

            }
            }()

            return NSError(domain: kAuthKitErrorDomain, code: codeK, userInfo: userInfoK)
    }
}
```

But when trying to extract from it

```
var err: NSError  = AuthKitError.SignInFailedInvalidUsernamePassword
println("error is : \(err)")
```

it fails, saying:

```
AuthKitError is not convertible to NSError
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is an instance property of the enum, and `AuthKitError.SignInFailedInvalidUsernamePassword` is an instance of the enum, so you have to explicitly read its value:

```
var err: NSError  = AuthKitError.SignInFailedInvalidUsernamePassword.error
                                                                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks very much Antonio !! D'oh ... :)

Comment: @Tino: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer to make it clear the problem is solved - that can help future readers